# Definition of odd topological K-theory using circles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I wanted to check whether the following characterization of odd complex topological $K$-theory is correct (reposted from Math.SE).

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then $K^{-1}(X)$ can be defined as $\tilde{K}^0((X\times\mathbb{R})^+)$, where $^+$ means one-point compactification.

Let $S^1\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be the unit circle. Since $(X\times\mathbb{R})^+$ is homeomorphic to $(X\times S^1)/(X\times\{1\})$,

**Question:** Can we say that an element of $\tilde{K}^0((X\times\mathbb{R})^+)$ is a difference of vector bundles $E$ and $F$ over $X\times S^1$ such that $E$ and $F$ are trivial over $X\times\{1\}$ and the virtual vector bundle $E-F$ has virtual dimension $0$ over $X\times\{1\}$?

Comment: I deleted my last comment because I convinced myself it was wrong, but now I am convinced it is ok again. I think you need an isomorphism of $E$ and $F$ on $X\times \{1\}$, and not trivializations. Conner and Floyd use this definition of $K^0$ (without the virtual dim=0, you might need to remove that, or maybe these cancel each other?) in their book The Relation of Cobordism to K-theory

Comment: @NoahRiggenbach Yes, the elements of relative K theory are pairs of vector bundles with an isomorphism between them on the restriction to the subspace. The virtual dimension 0 over the basepoint in reduced K theory is analogous to the isomorphism we need. So $\bar{K}^0 ((X \times S^1 )/X \times \{1\})$ can be described as pairs of vector bundles over $X \times S^1$ together with a chosen isomorphism of the restrictions to $X \times \{1\}$, up to a suitable equivalence relation.